# Problem with unit test and Custom Setting with @AuraEnabled

Tags: code-coverage, aura-enabled

There was a problem writing a unit test. I tried to use the usual HttpRequest and Mosk, but they do not work with Costom Setting. Here is my controller and test, which does not completely cover the code.

Mock:

```
@isTest global class WeatherMock implements HttpCalloutMock{

global String FAKE_RESPONSE_JSON = 'weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04d"}]';

global HTTPResponse respond (HttpRequest request){

    System.assertEquals('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Gomel&appid=378691a9e0004587376cd1ae5d6c0145', request.getEndpoint());
    System.assertEquals('GET', request.getMethod());

    HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();

    res.setBody(FAKE_RESPONSE_JSON);
    res.setStatusCode(200);
   return res;

}
```

}

Test:

```
@isTest private class TestWeather{

static testMethod void test_getLastSyncDetails(){

    Weather_Widget_Configuration__c testWeather = new Weather_Widget_Configuration__c(Name = 'Name', City__c = 'Gomel', Icon_Name__c = '04d', Weather__c = 'Clouds', Last_Synced_on__c = DateTime.now(), Temperature__c = 17);
    Insert testWeather; 

    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new WeatherMock());

    test.startTest();
    WeatherWidgetController testWidget = new WeatherWidgetController();

    WeatherWidgetController.getLastSyncDetails();
    test.stopTest();

}


static testMethod void test_refreshWeather(){

    Weather_Widget_Configuration__c testWeather = new Weather_Widget_Configuration__c(Name = 'Name', City__c = 'Gomel', Icon_Name__c = '04d', Weather__c = 'Clouds', Last_Synced_on__c = DateTime.now(), Temperature__c = 17);
    Insert testWeather; 

    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new WeatherMock());

    test.startTest();
    WeatherWidgetController testWidget = new WeatherWidgetController();

    WeatherWidgetController.refreshWeather('city');
    test.stopTest();

//System.assert(testWeather.City__c);

}
```

}

Controller:

```
public with sharing class WeatherWidgetController {

@AuraEnabled
public static Weather_Widget_Configuration__c getLastSyncDetails() {
    Weather_Widget_Configuration__c paramWeather = Weather_Widget_Configuration__c.getValues('Default');
    return paramWeather; 
}

@AuraEnabled
public static Weather_Widget_Configuration__c refreshWeather(String city){ 

    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    String unit = 'metric';

    String endpoint = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?';
    endpoint += 'q=' + city + '&appid=378691a9e0004587376cd1ae5d6c0145' + '&units=' + unit; 

    request.setEndpoint(endpoint);
    request.setMethod('GET');

    HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
    String responseBody = response.getBody();

    System.debug(responseBody);
    System.debug(response.getStatus());
    System.debug(response.getStatusCode());



    Map<String, Object> responseMap = (Map<String,Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(responseBody);
    Weather_Widget_Configuration__c paramWeather = getLastSyncDetails();

    if(paramWeather == null){
        paramWeather = new Weather_Widget_Configuration__c();
    }

    String cityName = String.valueOf(responseMap.get('name'));
    Map<String,Object> sysMap = (Map<String,Object>)responseMap.get('sys'); 
    String countryName = String.valueOf(sysMap.get('country'));
    Map<String,Object> mainMap = (Map<String,Object>)responseMap.get('main');

    Double temperature = Double.valueOf(mainMap.get('temp'));

    List<Object> weatherList = (List<Object>)responseMap.get('weather');

    Map<String,Object> weatherInfo = (Map<String,Object>)weatherList[0];
    String weatherDesc = String.valueOf(weatherInfo.get('description'));
    String weatherIcon = String.valueOf(weatherInfo.get('icon'));

    paramWeather.name = 'Default';
    paramWeather.City__c = cityName + ', ' + countryName;        
    paramWeather.Temperature__c = temperature;
    paramWeather.Weather__c = weatherDesc;
    paramWeather.Icon_Name__c = weatherIcon;

    paramWeather.Last_Synced_on__c = Datetime.now();
    upsert paramWeather;
    return paramWeather;
}
```

}

[image: It covers only 35% of the code, I need at least 75%]

**I rewrote the test, but the result is the same. In System.assert it throws an error no matter what I write.**

*Errors: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void assert(String) from the type System*

Comment: No assertions. That is not a unit test. Also, you are *not* setting a mock anywhere.

Comment: I need to call mock in "static testMethod void test_refreshWeather"

Comment: where is your Http Mock response? i would recommend go through this doc https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_httpcalloutmock.htm

Comment: Rewrote, but the response from the server fails. I tried to write assert in different ways, but still threw an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I knew that I had a problem with the output of information, and only now I realized what was wrong. I entered incorrect data and because of this the test did not pass.

```
static testMethod void test_refreshWeather(){

    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new WeatherMock());

    test.startTest();
    WeatherWidgetController testWidget = new WeatherWidgetController();

    Weather_Widget_Configuration__c res = WeatherWidgetController.refreshWeather('Gomel','378691a9e0004587376cd1ae5d6c0145');

    System.assertEquals('Default', res.name);
    System.assertEquals('378691a9e0004587376cd1ae5d6c0145', res.API_Key__c);
    System.assertEquals('Gomel, BY', res.City__c);
    System.assertEquals(5, res.Temperature__c);
    System.assertEquals('broken clouds', res.Weather__c);
    System.assertEquals('04d', res.Icon_Name__c);
    System.assertEquals(DateTime.now(), res.Last_Synced_on__c);
    test.stopTest();   
}
```

Mock:

@isTest
global class WeatherMock implements HttpCalloutMock{

```
global String FAKE_RESPONSE_JSON = '{"coord":{"lon":30.98,"lat":52.43},"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":5,"feels_like":-0.76,"temp_min":5,"temp_max":5,"pressure":993,"humidity":85},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":6,"deg":210},"clouds":{"all":75},"dt":1581428242,"sys":{"type":1,"id":8933,"country":"BY","sunrise":1581398486,"sunset":1581433161},"timezone":10800,"id":627907,"name":"Gomel","cod":200}';

global HTTPResponse respond (HttpRequest request){

    System.assertEquals('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Gomel&appid=378691a9e0004587376cd1ae5d6c0145&units=metric', request.getEndpoint());
    System.assertEquals('GET', request.getMethod());

    HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();

    res.setBody(FAKE_RESPONSE_JSON);
    res.setStatusCode(200);
   return res;

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You've got an assertion inside your mock -

```
 System.assertEquals('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Gomel&appid=378691a9e0004587376cd1ae5d6c0145', request.getEndpoint());
System.assertEquals('GET', request.getMethod());
```

Which is failing:

> FATAL_ERROR System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Gomel&appid=378691a9e0004587376cd1ae5d6c0145, Actual: https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=city&appid=378691a9e0004587376cd1ae5d6c0145&units=metric

You are missing off the &units=metric off the end of your assertion.

Comment: Thanks, but I can’t figure out how to correctly write the output of "System.assert (testWeather.City__c);" stops at this line "Weather_Widget_Configuration__c paramWeather = getLastSyncDetails();"

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Errors: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void assert(String) from the type System or Errors:Variable does not exist: City__c

Comment: Looks like 'testWeather.city__c' is a string, but you should be passing a boolean/condition into the System.assert method. For example - System.assert(testWeather.City__c == 'hello');  If you've got multiple errors happening, might be worth breaking the question down into smaller chunks and asking a new question.